# Missing environment variables while using npm(9.6.4) & node(19.9.0)

Tags: node.js, npm, sveltekit

I'm under the impression that you can find every single entry of your `package.json` as an environment variable. For example, `npm_package_dependencies_svelte` will give you the version of `svelte` that is installed or `npm_package_author_email` would give you the email field of the author property.

As per the npm doc's [(9.6.3)](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts#environment) The `package.json` fields are tacked onto the `npm_package_` prefix.

However, when I check to see what I have availible to me by running:

```json
"check-env": "node -e 'console.log(process.env)' | grep npm",
```

I only seem to have three in my SvelteKit project.

```bash
npm_package_json=/Users/**/Desktop/test-package-version-sveltekit-master/package.json
npm_package_name=test-package-version-svelte
npm_package_version=0.0.1
```

I'm at a loss as to why? I would like to access `npm_package_devDependencies_svelte`
But that variable is never created during `npm run dev`. Am I missing something important here?

```bash
npm -v 9.6.4
node -v 19.9.0
```

For clarification, I have a default skeleton sveltekit project set up and I'm trying to access the variables like so.

```
// src/hooks.server.ts
import {
    npm_package_version,
    npm_package_devDependencies_svelte,
} from '$env/static/private';

export const handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    console.log({
        packageVersion: npm_package_version,
        svelte: npm_package_devDependencies_svelte.split('^').join(''),
    });

    return await resolve(event);
};
```

I usually, wouldn't include this link as it pulls from S.O. but it's the most effective way to show replication of my issue. [CodeSandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/friendly-jang-pt7p21?file=%2FREADME.md)

Comment: I went to your CodeSandbox, opened the console, and all versions were displayed correctly, so the environment variables are present when the website is launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more explicit approach is to directly import the package.json file.

Using TypeScript, add the following to your `tsconfig.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": [..., "**/*.json"]
}
```

Then in `src/hooks.server.ts`:

```
import * as pj from "../package.json";

console.log({
    packageName: pj.name,
    packageVersion: pj.version,
    svelte: pj.devDependencies.svelte.split('^').join(''),
    typescript: pj.devDependencies.typescript.split('^').join('')
});
```

Hope that helps!